# Istio Analyze Referenced selector not found: "app=istio-private-ingressgateway"

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, gateway, istio-gateway, istio-operator

I have a gateway living in the `gateways` namespace and istio-ingressgateway living in `istio-system` namespace.

The ingressgateway has the label `app=istio-private-ingressgateway` as follows

```
k get pod -n istio-system -l "app=istio-private-ingressgateway"
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-private-ingressgateway-8657c4fcdb-6h4qb   1/1     Running   0          20d
istio-private-ingressgateway-8657c4fcdb-bwkvp   1/1     Running   0          20d
```

The traffic works just fine and I am able to access the gateway and whatever service behind it. But when I do `istioctl analyze -n gateways` I see the following error:

```
Error [IST0101] (Gateway gateways/private-gateway) Referenced selector not found: "app=istio-private-ingressgateway"
```

I have verified that the `PILOT_SCOPE_GATEWAY_TO_NAMESPACE` flag in istiod configuration is set to `false`. So it should be able to match the selectors in other namespaces.

I have also tried putting my gateway inside the `istio-system` namespace, but it is still complaining about the same error.
I am using istio version `1.16.0`.

It seems a very weird error because if the gateway cannot match to selectors then how can it direct traffics? Or maybe it's just an `istioctl analyze` bug? Just trying to figure if there is anything wrong with my setup here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a similar issue in previous [istio version1.13.2](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/38636) and the root cause of this issue as reported in the [PR: 3602](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/36062) is istioctl command is not able to read the correct revision. Since you are facing a similar issue, you can reopen the same bug or create a new one with istio [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues) and they will help in solving this issue.